# Does Hindu scriptures say anything about unvedic religion?

Tags: non-hindu

Apart from Bhavishya Purana (which is widely believed to be interpolated text), does any old Hindu scripture say about people who follow unvedic religion ?
Particularly religions of foreigners and Mlechhas ?

Comment: There are mention of Cārvākas, Jainas, Bauddhas, etc. in several śāstras. But these aren't mlecchas and also not Abrahamics. And mlecchas are an extremely wide category in themselves, it's not limited to Muslims or Christians. If you want to search for Islam, Christianity, Zoroastrianism in Hindu śāstras, your search would be in vain. We don't care about them really. There's a mention of Islam in Kālacakra tantra (which is a Bauddha śāstra) and some other Kālacakra śāstras. https://journals.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/index.php/jiabs/article/download/8878/2785 ; http://www.jstor.org/stable/41926812

Comment: Bauddha bhikṣu's Hyecho's travelogue, mentions Muslims and Zoroastrianism, as he travelled in some regions of the west after India. Also, some later Jaina texts mention Islam, because these were written during the reigns of Islamic (particularly Mughal) rulers in India.

Answer (score 0):

The only non Vedic religions that most scriptures speak of are Buddhism and Jainism.

> Śukadeva Gosvāmī continued speaking to Mahārāja Parīkṣit: My dear
> King, the King of Koṅka, Veṅka and Kuṭaka whose name was Arhat, heard
> of the activities of Ṛṣabhadeva and, imitating Ṛṣabhadeva’s
> principles, introduced a new system of religion. Taking advantage of
> Kali-yuga, the age of sinful activity, King Arhat, being bewildered,
> gave up the Vedic principles, which are free from risk, and concocted
> a new system of religion opposed to the Vedas. That was the beginning
> of the Jain dharma. Many other so-called religions followed this
> atheistic system

[**SB 5.6.9**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/6/9/)

> When the atheists, after being well versed in the Vedic scientific
> knowledge, annihilate inhabitants of different planets, flying unseen
> in the sky on well-built rockets prepared by the great scientist Maya,
> the Lord will bewilder their minds by dressing Himself attractively as
> Buddha and will preach on subreligious principles

**[SB 2.7.37](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/7/37/)**

Comment: Mostly regarding puranas btw. Obviously nastika faiths aren't seen in a good light, but only later scriptures mention Jain and Buddhas manufactured "Dharma"

Comment: @Haridasa Just saying, Traditionalist schools see Puranas as bonafide works of Veda vyasa, not as later written scriptures

Comment: True, but like only Vedanta I believe even see the Puranas as somewhat authentic I do not know about Yoga and I am fairly certain all other darshanas only see Vedic authority.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of OP. It's a useless answer, as the OP is concerned in 'religions' of mlecchas and not Avaidika sampradāyas and darśanas, as is clearly specified already.

Answer (score 0):

Manusmriti ch 12

> या वेदबाह्याः स्मृतयो याश्च काश्च कुदृष्टयः।
>
> सर्वास्ता निष्फलाः प्रेत्य तमोनिष्ठा हि ताः स्मृताः॥
>
> उत्पद्यन्ते च्यवन्ते च यान्यतोऽन्यानि कानि चित् ।
>
> तान्यर्वाक्कालिकतया निष्फलान्यनृतानि च ॥
>
> Those ‘revealed texts’ that are outside the Veda, as also all the
> false theories, are useless, even when carried to perfection; as they
> have been declared to be founded on ‘darkness.’—(95)
>
> Those other (doctrines) which spring up and perish are all worthless
> and false, being of modern growth.—(96)

On [Athiesm](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-03-sa.html)(if one considers it religion)

यक्ष उवाच। कः पण्डितः पुमान्ज्ञेयो नास्तिकः कश्च उच्यते। को मूर्खः कश्चकामः स्यात्को मत्सर इति स्मृतः ॥ 3-314-99

Yaksha said: Which man should be understood to be a Pandita? Who is called a Naastika (Atheist)? Who is a fool? What is Kaama (desire) What is Matsara?

युधिष्ठिर उवाच। धर्मज्ञः पण्डितो ज्ञेयो नास्तिको मूर्ख उच्यते। कामः संसारहेतुश्च हृत्तापो मत्सरः स्मृतः ॥ 3-314-100

Yudhisthira Said: The knower of Dharma should be understood to be a Pandita, a Naastika is called a fool, and the fool is a Naastika...